# Strong numbers in C#

Tags: c#, function

I have to code a function that prints every "strong" integer, between 1 and n. These integers verify the sum of the factorials of each of its digits is equal to itself. For example:
 145 because 1! + 4! + 5! = 145.

So far what I did:

```
    public static long Fac(long n)
    {
        var i = 1;
        for (; n > 1; n--)
        {
            i *= (int) n;
        }
        return i;
    }
    public static bool IsStrong(int n)
    {

        var i = 1;
        var sum = 0;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            i = n % 10;
            sum += (int)Fac(i);
            n = n / 10;
        }

        if (sum == n)
            return true;
        else

            return false;

    } 

    public static void Print_Strong(int n)
    {
        if (IsStrong(n))
            Console.Write("{0} is STRONG!  -W", n);
        else
            Console.Write("{0} is not strong. -w", n);
    }
```

When I run it, it never leaves the loop .

Comment: n >= 0 ? It will never be less than zero. But why not using the debugger ? You will learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your code:

- `while (n >= 0)` should be `while (n > 0)` otherwise you will never
  leave the loop.
- When the sum is equal to n you have to return true
- `sum == n` will never be true because n will be 0 in the end

Here's a fix:

```
public static bool IsStrong(int n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    int n2 = n;

    while (n2 > 0)
    {
        sum += Fac(n2 % 10);
        n2 = n2 / 10;
    }

    return sum == n;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you.